# Using Hibernate 6 with WildFly

Tags: hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to use the most recent version of Hibernate (6) on WildFly 26.0.1.
I have created the following structure under system/layers/base/org/hibernate;

```
6.0
├── hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar
└── module.xml
```

Here is the module.xml file:

```
<module name="org.hibernate:6.0" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.9">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-6.0.0.Final.jar"/>
  
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="java.desktop"/>
        <module name="java.instrument"/>
        <module name="java.management"/>
        <module name="java.naming"/>
        <module name="java.sql"/>
        <module name="com.fasterxml.classmate"/>
        <!--WFLY-14219 Remove deprecated <module name="javax.api"/> -->
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.enterprise.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>
        <module name="com.sun.xml.bind"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.javassist" export="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.spi"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.jandex"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3" services="import"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache" services="import" optional="true"/>
        <module name="net.bytebuddy"/>
        <module name="java.xml"/>
    <module name="com.h2database.h2" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I'm referencing the Hibernate version in persistence.xml as follows:

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:6.0"/>
```

However, when I deploy the application it fails to link some Classes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/hibernate/HibernateException (Module "org.hibernate:6.0" version 6.0.0.Final from local module loader @3668d4 (finder: local module finder @1c3b9394 (roots: /home/user1/jboss/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/modules,/home/user1/jboss/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base))): jakarta/persistence/PersistenceException
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:350)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:276)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:79)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:192)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.hibernate@5.3.24.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:131)
    ... 25 more

18:16:48,622 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "hibernate.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"hibernate.war#primary\".__FIRST_PHASE__" => "org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl] as strategy [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl] as strategy [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/hibernate/HibernateException (Module \"org.hibernate:6.0\" version 6.0.0.Final from local module loader @3668d4 (finder: local module finder @1c3b9394 (roots: /home/user1/jboss/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/modules,/home/user1/jboss/wildfly-26.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base))):
```

jakarta/persistence/PersistenceException"}}
Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using WildFly 26 Preview?

Comment: No thanks it's the Jakarta EE 8 version. I suspect there org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate5-3 needs to be replaced too but there's no 6 final version of it available.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` because you're attempting to use a Jakarta EE 9 compliant JPA implementation with a Jakarta EE 8 server. You've either got to stick with the Hibernate version in WildFly or move to Jakarta EE 9.